# Verse or quote environment inside list

Tags: lists, indentation, enumerate

I want to explain a poem line by line for a poetry class, and the effect I want to get is 
[image]

But I encountered some difficulty to format the three lines after point 2. Google does not provide much help. How should I do this? A minimal template is provided below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[itemindent = 3em, leftmargin = 0em, itemsep = 1ex, partopsep = 0ex, parsep = 1ex, listparindent = 2em]
\item The first line of the poem

Some explanations
\item \begin{quote}% How to get these lines formatted?
The second line of the poem\\
The third line of the poem\\
The fourth line of the poem
\end{quote}

Some other explanations that may contain several paragraphs

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that with the `verse` package, and even number the verses. This is an example-code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[lf]{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{verse, etoolbox}
 \usepackage{enumitem}
 \AtBeginEnvironment{verse}{\itshape}

\settowidth{\versewidth}{In the midst of the word he was trying to say,}
\poemlines{1}
\verselinenumfont{\footnotesize\upshape}
\setlength\vgap{-\dimexpr\leftmargini + \labelsep\relax}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[itemindent = 3em, leftmargin = 0em, itemsep = 1ex, partopsep = 0ex, parsep = 1ex, listparindent = 2em]
\item %

\begin{verse}[\versewidth]% How to get these lines formatted?
\vin In the midst of the word he was trying to say,\\[3ex]
\end{verse}

Some explanations
\item

\begin{verse}[\versewidth]\setverselinenums{2}{1}
     \vin     In the midst of his laughter and glee,\\
     He had softly and suddenly vanished away — \\
     For the Snark \emph{was} a Boojum, you see.\\[3ex]
\end{verse}

Some other explanations that may contain several paragraphs

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help. The code `\setlength\vgap{-\dimexpr\leftmargini + \labelsep\relax}` solves the indentation problem.